# ¿como usar adecuadamente la funcion requestAnimationFrame() en un canvas desde un objeto en javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Buenos dias estimada comunidad, necesito la ayuda de ustedes sucede que estoy realizando un programa en javascript que manipula el DOM canvas con el fin de refrescar nombres aleatoriamente para ello en mi codigo declaro mi objeto y lo instancio correctamente:

```
let canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");

let context= canvas.getContext("2d");

var window_height=window.innerHeight;
var window_width=window.innerWidth;

canvas.width=window_width;
canvas.height=window_height;

canvas.style.background="#ff0";

class Texto{
    constructor(xpos,ypos,width,color,text){
        this.xpos=xpos;
        this.ypos=ypos;
        this.width=width;
        this.color=color;
        this.text=text;
    }
    draw(context){
        context.beginPath();

        context.strokeStyle=this.color;
        context.textAlign="center";
        context.textBaseline="middle";
        context.font="20px Arial";
        context.fillText(this.text,this.xpos,this.ypos);
        context.stroke();
        context.closePath();
    }

    update(text){
        context.clearRect(0,0,window_width,window_height);
        this.draw(context);
        this.text=text;

    }
}

let texto= new Texto(100,300,60,"red","Tefy");
texto.draw(context);
```

Pero cuando quiero ya utilizar la función requestAnimationFrame en el código a continuación para refrescar el canvas y cambiar de nombres al azar, en el canvas me sale un conteo de números:

```
let detener;
let func = (a) => {
    //console.log(a)
    detener=requestAnimationFrame(func);    
    texto.update(a);

}

func("charlie");
func("jose");
```

Luego de haber buscado y no encuentro algun paso para esto, por favor estaría muy agradecido de su ayuda
Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es que el callback (la funcion que recibe requestAnimationFrame) recibe un parametro que es timestamp, por lo tanto en el primer llamado a ese callback tu asignas ese timestamp al texto y por eso te salen numeros.

Puede convertir el callback en una funcion que llame a tun funcion `func` con el mismo parámetro `a`, así:

```js
let canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
console.log(canvas);
let context= canvas.getContext("2d");

var window_height=window.innerHeight;
var window_width=window.innerWidth;

canvas.width=window_width;
canvas.height=window_height;

canvas.style.background="#ff0";

class Texto{
    constructor(xpos,ypos,width,color,text){
        this.xpos=xpos;
        this.ypos=ypos;
        this.width=width;
        this.color=color;
        this.text=text;
    }
    draw(context){
        context.beginPath();

        context.strokeStyle=this.color;
        context.textAlign="center";
        context.textBaseline="middle";
        context.font="20px Arial";
        context.fillText(this.text,this.xpos,this.ypos);
        context.stroke();
        context.closePath();
    }

    update(text){
        context.clearRect(0,0,window_width,window_height);
        this.draw(context);
        this.text=text;

    }
}

let texto= new Texto(50,50,60,"red","Tefy");
texto.draw(context);

let detener;
let func = (a) => {
    console.log(a)
    detener=requestAnimationFrame(() => func(a)); //-->EL CAMBIO ESTA AQUI
    texto.update(a);    
}

func("charlie");
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: Gracias por la corrección me sirve bastante. Saludos (: